# Issues while installing Diaspora in Windows

Tags: eventmachine, diaspora

I am trying to install diaspora in windows and when I run my bundle install, It throws an error when installing eventmachine. Then I came to know that the lastest version of eventmachine is not supported in windows with ruby 1.9.2. Eventmachine gem is not in the 
gemfile, hence must be a dependent gem. How can I run diaspora in my local windows machine?

```
    Installing eventmachine (0.12.10) with native extensions D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/inst
aller.rb:529:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::Ext
ensionBuildError)

        D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... no
checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for windows.h... yes
checking for winsock.h... yes
checking for main() in -lkernel32... yes
checking for main() in -lrpcrt4... yes
checking for main() in -lgdi32... yes
checking for main() in -lssl... no
creating Makefile

make
g++ -I. -ID:/Program_Files/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I/D/Program_Files/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ba
ckward -I/D/Program_Files/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_TBR -D
HAVE_RB_THREAD_CHECK_INTS -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_WIN32 -DHAVE_WINDOWS_H -DHAVE_WINSOCK_H -DWITHOUT_SSL -DHAVE_MAKE_PAIR
    -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializer
s -Wno-long-long   -o binder.o -c binder.cpp
In file included from project.h:137:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
binder.h:35:34: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:138:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
em.h:91:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:92:76: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:93:56: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:95:57: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:96:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:97:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:98:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:99:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:101:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:106:42: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:123:45: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:132:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:45:61: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:46:112: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:47:69: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:49:73: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:62:75: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:63:74: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:64:77: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:65:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:99:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:100:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:102:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:105:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
g++ -I. -ID:/Program_Files/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I/D/Program_Files/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ba
ckward -I/D/Program_Files/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_TBR -D
HAVE_RB_THREAD_CHECK_INTS -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_WIN32 -DHAVE_WINDOWS_H -DHAVE_WINSOCK_H -DWITHOUT_SSL -DHAVE_MAKE_PAIR
    -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializer
s -Wno-long-long   -o cmain.o -c cmain.cpp
In file included from project.h:137:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
binder.h:35:34: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:138:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
em.h:91:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:92:76: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:93:56: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:95:57: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:96:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:97:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:98:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:99:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:101:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:106:42: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:123:45: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:132:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:45:61: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:46:112: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:47:69: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:49:73: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:62:75: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:63:74: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:64:77: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:65:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:99:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:100:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:102:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:105:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:98:71: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:109:122: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:119:79: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:129:83: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:260:85: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:270:84: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:280:88: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:290:51: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:300:70: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:320:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:546:70: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:669:68: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp: In function 'int evma_send_file_data_to_connection(long unsigned int, const char*)':
cmain.cpp:752:6: error: cannot convert 'stat*' to '_stati64*' for argument '2' to 'int _fstati64(int, _stati64*)'
make: *** [cmain.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10 for inspection
.
Results logged to D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/ext/gem_make.out
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:507:in `block in build_extensions'
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:482:in `each'
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:482:in `build_extensions'
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:156:in `install'
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/source.rb:101:in `block in ins
tall'
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:78:in
`preserve_paths'
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/source.rb:91:in `install'
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:58:in `block (2 l
evels) in run'
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:93:in
`with_build_args'
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:57:in `block in r
un'
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `block in ea
ch'
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:49:in `run'
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/cli.rb:222:in `install'
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run
'
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:
in `invoke_task'
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatc
h'
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `st
art'
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
        from D:/Program_Files/Ruby192/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `gem 'eventmachine', '~> 1.0.0.beta.4.1'` to the Gemfile?

Comment: Could you add the error to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know RVM for Linux? There is a similar tool for windows called pik, check it out here: http://www.ruby-on-rails-outsourcing.com/2010/07/28/ruby-version-manager-for-windows/

Comment: U mean to say I have to use another version of ruby for diaspora to work?

Answer (score 0):

As of April 2012 I installed eventmachine on Windows 7 using:

gem install --pre eventmachine

This install eventmachine 1.0.0 beta 4 mingw.

(Note I have mingw installed).

Answer (score 0):

First, add the following line to your GemFile:

```
gem 'eventmachine', '~> 1.0.0.rc.4'
```

Second, update eventmachine in the bundle with:

```
bundle update eventmachine
```